# Displaying equivalent to SQL pivot table using Linq against Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq

I've been struggling for a few days to display something like Pivoting a dynamic table on SQL, using Linq. I don't actually want to create a pivoted table, I just want to display the results as if it was a pivoted table.

I have two entities:

Category:

```
 public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public ICollection<StaticEvent> StaticEvents { get; set; }
```

StaticEvent:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId {get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset Time {get; set; }

        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string Comment {get; set;}
```

I'm trying to generate a table showing the COUNT of STATIC EVENTS per CATEGORY PER YEARMONTH. So the rows would be the YEARMONTH, the columns would be the Categories and the values would be the COUNT.

[image]

I got to the point where I can count the STATIC EVENTS per YEARMONTH:

```
var query = _context.Categories
            .SelectMany(c => c.StaticEvents )
            .GroupBy(c => 
               new {
                   Year = c.Time.Year,
                   Month = c.Time.Month
               })
            .Select( x=> new {YearMonth = x.Key, Count = x.Count()})
            .ToList();

            foreach (var x in query)
            {Console.WriteLine($"Month = {x.YearMonth.Year},{x.YearMonth.Month},  , Count = " + x.Count);}
```

but I'm lost about what to do from here.

Answer (score 0):

If Categories is unknown values which are stored in database, it is not possible to do that via LINQ without dynamic query creation.

There is query which do the job when you known categories on the compile time. Since you have not specified EF version, I have emulated `Count` with `Sum`:

```cs
var query = _context.Categories
    .SelectMany(c => c.StaticEvents)
    .GroupBy(c => 
        new {
            Year = c.Time.Year,
            Month = c.Time.Month
        })
    .Select(x => new {
        YearMonth = x.Key, 
        Cat1 = x.Sum(z => z.CategoryId == 1 ? 1 : 0),
        Cat2 = x.Sum(z => z.CategoryId == 2 ? 1 : 0),
        Cat3 = x.Sum(z => z.CategoryId == 3 ? 1 : 0),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: yeah I need to be able to add categories that aren't know, as new categories can be added at any time. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: Better SQL. Currently I do not see benefits of doing that via LINQ. Efforts and skills are high.

Comment: I can do it in SQL easily, but then how to read the results of the pivoted table, since it's not an actual database table?

Comment: By old plain DataReader.